# Preserve existing bits?

Tags: assembly, arm

Here are two functions that each store a bit at address **0x20200020**:

```
.globl arm_func_1
    arm_func_1:
    ldr r0,=0x20200020
    mov r1,#1
    lsl r1,#16
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl arm_func_2
    arm_func_2
    ldr r0,=0x20200020
    mov r1,#1
    lsl r1,#17
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

After calling `arm_func_1` the content at address **0x20200020** is this:

```
0x20200020 = 00000000000000010000000000000000
```

When calling `arm_func_2` after returning from `arm_func_1` the content at address **0x20200020** is this:

```
0x20200020 = 00000000000000100000000000000000
```

How can I avoid overwriting existing bits at address **0x20200020**, and only modify a single bit, so the result would be this:

```
0x20200020 = 00000000000000110000000000000000
```

I'm looking for a method that will work in multiple cases, so I don't have to keep track of values at memory addresses before calling a function.

Comment: Are these function potentially running at the same time?  Also, which architechure?  Also, is it always these bits or do you have a choice?  If you can use other bits, you can use *byte/char* for the setting and *word* for the reading.  Otherwise, you need *read-modify-write* and may need locking if the code runs in parallel.  If you don't run in parallel or have the freedom to choose the bits, then auslen has the correct answer (although the shifts aren't needed and you can OR with a constant; much like the compiler did).  Also, you need to initialize the memory before hand (to zero?)

Comment: The architecture is ARMv6 and there is no multitasking implemented, so the functions will not run at the same time. Memory address 0x20200020 is the register where GPIOs are configured. After calling `arm_func_1` a specific GPIO pin has been configured. The function `arm_func_2` will configure another GPIO pin, but at the same time overwrite the configuration just made by `arm_func_1`, this is what I try to avoid. There are multiple GPIO pins to configure, so the bit pattern not predictable beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first read the value at address, `or` it with your requested bit then write it back. May be like below:

```
.globl arm_func
    arm_func:
    ldr r0,=0x20200020
    ldr r2,[r0]
    mov r1,#1
    lsl r1,#16
    orr r2, r1
    str r2,[r0]
    bx lr
```

or for a more generic approach you can get help from `gcc`:

```
$ cat updatebit.c 
void f(unsigned int *addr, int bit) {
    *addr |= 1 << bit;
}

$ objdump -d updatebit.o

updatebit.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <f>:
   0:   e5903000    ldr r3, [r0]
   4:   e3a02001    mov r2, #1
   8:   e1831112    orr r1, r3, r2, lsl r1
   c:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. This is not part of my orginial question, but would it also be possible to change a bit from 1 to 0, and still preserve all the other bits? Bitwise OR would not work in that case?

Comment: of course it is possible to clear the bit. you can use bic (bit clear) instruction instead of orr to clear the bit(s) you want. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABGIEBE.html But I suggest you to learn by doing that's what I tried to instruct you in C example. you could have figure out BIC instruction yourself.